# How to use overlay Vkeyboard on Canvas in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I have a code of Vkeyboard written in tkinter using `grid`. I want to implement it in my canvas and above on the background image.

Following is my code.

```
from tkinter import *


Keyboard_App = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(Keyboard_App, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

background = PhotoImage(file="Images/background.png")
canvas.create_image(400,400,image=background, tags="B")

buttons = [
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '=',
    'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '<-',
    'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', '"',
    'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '/', 'SHIFT',
    ' Space ',
]
curBut = [-1,-1]
buttonL = [[]]
entry = Text(Keyboard_App, width=97, height=8)
entry.grid(row=0, columnspan=15)

varRow = 1
varColumn = 0

def leftKey(event):
    if curBut == [-1,-1]:
        curBut[:] = [0,0]
        buttonL[0][0].configure(highlightbackground='red')
    elif curBut[0] == 4:
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]].configure(highlightbackground='#d9d9d9')
        curBut[:] = [0,10]
        buttonL[0][10].configure(highlightbackground='red')
    else:
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]].configure(highlightbackground='#d9d9d9')
        curBut[:] = [curBut[0], (curBut[1]-1)%11]
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]%11].configure(highlightbackground='red')

def rightKey(event):
    if curBut == [-1,-1]:
        curBut[:] = [0,0]
        buttonL[0][0].configure(highlightbackground='red')
    elif curBut[0] == 4:
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]].configure(highlightbackground='#d9d9d9')
        curBut[:] = [0,0]
        buttonL[0][0].configure(highlightbackground='red')
    else:
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]].configure(highlightbackground='#d9d9d9')
        curBut[:] = [curBut[0], (curBut[1]+1)%11]
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]%11].configure(highlightbackground='red')

def upKey(event):
    if curBut == [-1,-1]:
        curBut[:] = [0,0]
        buttonL[0][0].configure(highlightbackground='red')
    elif curBut[0] == 0:
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]].configure(highlightbackground='#d9d9d9')
        curBut[:] = [(curBut[0]-1)%5, 0]
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]%11].configure(highlightbackground='red')
    else:
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]].configure(highlightbackground='#d9d9d9')
        curBut[:] = [(curBut[0]-1)%5, curBut[1]]
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]%11].configure(highlightbackground='red')

def downKey(event):
    if curBut == [-1,-1]:
        curBut[:] = [0,0]
        buttonL[0][0].configure(highlightbackground='red')
    elif curBut[0] == 3:
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]].configure(highlightbackground='#d9d9d9')
        curBut[:] = [(curBut[0]+1)%5, 0]
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]%11].configure(highlightbackground='red')
    else:
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]].configure(highlightbackground='#d9d9d9')
        curBut[:] = [(curBut[0]+1)%5, curBut[1]]
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]%11].configure(highlightbackground='red')

def select(value, x, y):
    if curBut != [-1,-1]:
        buttonL[curBut[0]][curBut[1]].configure(highlightbackground='#d9d9d9')
    curBut[:] = [x,y]
    buttonL[x][y].configure(highlightbackground='red')
    if value == "<-":
        input = entry.get("1.0", 'end-2c')
        entry.delete("1.0", END)
        entry.insert("1.0", input, END)

    elif value == " Space ":
        entry.insert(END, ' ')

    elif value == "Tab":
        entry.insert(END, '   ')

    else:
        entry.insert(END, value)

for button in buttons:
    if button != " Space ":
        but = Button(Keyboard_App, text=button, width=5, bg="#000000", fg="#ffffff", highlightthickness=4, 
                       activebackground="#ffffff", activeforeground="#000000", relief="raised", padx=12,
                       pady=4, bd=4, command=lambda x=button, i=varRow-1, j=varColumn: select(x, i, j))
        buttonL[varRow-1].append(but)
        but.grid(row=varRow, column=varColumn)

    if button == " Space ":
        but = Button(Keyboard_App, text=button, width=60, bg="#000000", fg="#ffffff", highlightthickness=4, 
                       activebackground="#ffffff", activeforeground="#000000", relief="raised", padx=4,
                       pady=4, bd=4, command=lambda x=button, i=varRow-1, j=varColumn: select(x, i, j))
        buttonL[varRow-1].append(but)
        but.grid(row=6, columnspan=16)

    varColumn += 1
    if varColumn > 10:
        varColumn = 0
        varRow += 1
        buttonL.append([])

Keyboard_App.bind('<Left>', leftKey)
Keyboard_App.bind('<Right>', rightKey)
Keyboard_App.bind('<Up>', upKey)
Keyboard_App.bind('<Down>', downKey)
Keyboard_App.mainloop()
```

This is causing an error says `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack` because I' can't use `grid` and `pack` both in the single frame. I am so confused with the code like how should I resolve this. Can anyone give me a clue how to get on the right track using my code ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the error mentions, you simply can't use both `grid` and `pack` in the same frame. You need to remove the call to `.pack()` for it to work.

```py
canvas = Canvas(Keyboard_App, width=400, height=400)
canvas.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

background = PhotoImage(file="Images/background.png")
canvas.create_image(400,400,image=background, tags="B")
```

You also need to call `.place()` for it to know where to display on your window. `relwidth` and `relweight` are just the width and weight relative to the master object, and are optional here.

Note that this doesn't resize the image correctly, though, if your old code did manage it. I recommend using the library `PIL` if you want to resize it, I can show you code that would work in your case ; I believe it's also possible simply with your `PhotoImage`, but not practical.

Comment: Thankyou for commenting! By doing this, It resolved that error but can we get the background image first and then the VKeyboard and `Entry` on it ? \

Comment: @Deepakpal My mistake, I forgot you had a background image. I'll edit it shortly.

Comment: @Deepakpal Edited and added a lot more details!

Comment: Thank you soo much! It's working!! Just having one issue, when  I tried to replace `Entry` with `canvas.create_text`, it's showing this error -> `self.canvas_textbox.insert(END, value)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'`

Comment: @Deepakpal There's no `canvas_textbox` in your code, but as the error indicates, it's an `int` on which you're trying to call a method named `.insert()` which it obviously doesn't have since it's just a number.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, it was my mistake in code that's why I was getting error.

Comment: I want to place somewhere else the Vkeyboard, currently it's placed on `0,0`. Is there any way to do that please ?

Comment: When I change the value of `x and y` from here `.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)`, then inside of moving the keyboard, whole canvas is moving. Should I use another canvas for it ? But if I will do it, then I will get issue with background. Please help me with the code. Thank you soo much for your efforts!!!

Comment: Hey! Please reply

Comment: @Deepakpal It's December 26th, I've been on holiday and I don't want to be active on SO. Please make another thread if you're in a hurry.

Comment: @Deepakpal Was taking another look at it; you should indeed use another canvas or other container (a Frame may work, I'm not sure) if you want to choose its position easily. However, why didn't putting them in another canvas work? Can you edit your question with the new code?